# gRPC not generating java_plugin

Tags: java, gradle, grpc

I am trying to use Google's gRPC tool.  I followed the instructions [here](https://github.com/grpc/grpc-common/blob/master/java/javatutorial.md) but when I run my protoc code, I get the following error:  **compiler/build/binaries/java_pluginExecutable/java_plugin: program not found or is not executable**.  Any help is appreciated.  I'm on OSX 10.9.5 with Gradle 2.3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed my problem.  I was not adding a reference to the java_plugin in my gradle file.

Comment: Would you explain more about the java_plugin reference ?! I'm facing the same problem and grpc_java_plugin file is not generated.

Comment: I had to look at the sample project that came with grpc.  Inside of build.gradle, I saw that there was the line `protobufCodeGenPlugins = ["java_plugin:$rootDir/compiler/build/binaries/java_pluginExecutable/java_plugin"]`.  That line provides to build script with the java plugin.  It fixed my problem and it should fix yours!

Answer (score 1):

Did you get any errors when building the compiler plugin with gradle?
Did you check if the `java_plugin` is actually there?

Also if you run `protoc` from within the examples directory, you have to adjust your path to `"../compiler/build/binaries/java_pluginExecutable/java_plugin"`

Also there is generally no need to run `protoc` yourself. Simply running `../gradew build` from within the examples directory should do everything for you.

Comment: i did not get any errors.  it builds perfectly fine from the example repo and the example server/client.